# how to see the latest commits without merge or commit the current changes?

Tags: git, merge, commit

I am using git. I have made some changes in my working directory. the code is not yet complete and because of that I don't want to commit it now. But for some reasons I have to see immediately the latest commits in master branch.

I know that I can see them by 'git checkout' but if I do that I will lose the changes in my working directory.

I thought of creating a branch and keeping my changes there but the problem is that still when I want to see the recent commits in master branch, git tries to merge these two branches which I don't want.

can someone help or tell me what I said is correct ot not?

Comment: Git does not try to merge anything unless you actually run `git merge`.  You can always run `git log master` to view commits regardless of what branch you currently have checked out.

Answer (score 1):

You can stage your changes, stash them with `git stash`, look at whatever you need, and then do `git stash pop`.

Here is the [relevant documentation](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing).

In a nutshell, `git stash` saves your working directory on a stack and checks out HEAD. You can then do whatever you want with stashes - apply them as patches, list them with `git stash list` and more.

Comment: do i need 'git add' before that?

Comment: Yes, I will add this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What IDE are you using? If you are on IDEA you could shelf your changes and perform the checkout without losing anything../

Comment: i am using eclipse in linux. how can i shelf my changes?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't have this feature I guess. What you could do is, like you said, create a new branch with your local changes (git checkout -b new_branch_name), change to master and git pull.